# Node.js stay connected without close after write

Tags: javascript, node.js, connection-pooling

I try to explain my problem :

- I have a file per user connect: *user1.txt*, *user2.txt* (which contain javascript code)
- I have a script that updated them depending of the evolution of the application
- each user call a file demo.php:

**Client HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>demo game</title>
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://127.0.0.1:8080"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="messages"></div>
  </body>
</body>
</html>
```

**Node server.js:**

```
    var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){

               setInterval(function() {
                    mycode = html.readFileSync(__dirname+'/user1.txt');

                    socket.end(mycode+"\n");
                    console.log('data sent'+mycode);

                }, 1000);

         });

    server.listen(8080);
```

And let say the content of *user1.txt* is: `$("#messages").append("<br> hello");`

Sending the contain of *user1.txt*, is ok and execute on the client side, but, if the *user1.txt* contain change, I see it on the `console.log('data sent'+mycode);` , I suppose it what sent but not execute, why ??

I try with `write()` instead of `end()`, and I try with :

```
var net = require('net');
var html = require('fs');
var server = net.createServer({ allowHalfOpen: true},....
```

same!

once again : how can I sent 'live javascript code', on client side ?

thank in advance

Dany

Comment: Vadim Baryshev's answer is right. One note too: I can't see that `socket` is defined. And I doubt, that the `setTimeout()` can be or at least should be used in that way (I'm not very familar with Node.js though) (but maybe this was just debugging for your, then I apologize).

Comment: Even if you use `write()` to send data, don't forget to end the sending with `end()`. As it is said in Node.js's doc: _Finishes sending the request._

Answer (score 1):

Browser can load your script before rendering of `<div id="messages"></div>`. In this case your code executes, bit without any effect. Try to change your code in `user1.txt` like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#messages").append("<br> hello");
});
```

Comment: Sorry Vadim, same I see in log that I get the new content of user1.txt, but no changes on the browser side

Comment: Sorry, my fail. I didn't fully understand your question. You trying to stream data from user1.txt to browser in infinite loop (setInterval)? If yes - you are using wrong way. You need to use socket for that. `Webscoket` or `socket.io` should work good. Every new javascript command will be sended to client as separate message. And you can execute it.